# Kafka Jvm out of memory

Tags: java, apache-kafka

have 1 kafka broker and 1 zookeeper on same VM with following specs

```
Vcpu: 96

RAM: 442GB
```

And for testing purposes I want to test how many partitions can will be on broker so I do the following steps

```
    Create topic with 128 partitions
    Scale this topics to 50.000 partitions
```

Then when number of partitions reach the 32168 partitions, kafka brokers Exited with following error log hs_err_pid.log

```
 head -100 hs_err_pid120814.log



 There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

 Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 262144 bytes for committing reserved memory.

 Possible reasons:

   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space

 Possible solutions:

   Reduce memory load on the system

   Increase physical memory or swap space

   Check if swap backing store is full

   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)

   Decrease number of Java threads

  Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)

   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=

 This output file may be truncated or incomplete.



  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2795), pid=120814, tid=0x00007f4ba5e2d700



 JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_362-b09) (build 1.8.0_362-b09)

 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.362-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
```

But why Out Of memory? Here is Kafka heap size

**Environment="KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xms1G -Xmx96G"**

and here is pick RAM consumption when partitions is created

```
free -h

          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available

Mem: 442Gi 7.4Gi 435Gi 2.2Gi 4.5Gi 435Gi

Swap: 0B 0B 0B
```

Why it is exited because of RAM? I have no limits in my linux system

```
ulimit -a

core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited

data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited

scheduling priority             (-e) 0

file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited

pending signals                 (-i) unlimited

max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited

max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited

open files                      (-n) 1048576

pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8

POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) unlimited

real-time priority              (-r) 0

stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited

cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited

max user processes              (-u) unlimited

virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited

file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Realistically, you should not create a JVM max heap size that large, anyway. GC pauses will take forever.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of errors can not only occur because the total amount of heap space is exhausted, but also when the number of memory-mapped areas is exhausted.

In Linux, the maximum per-process number of map areas is controlled by vm.max_map_count sysctl parameter (which defaults to 65536). So, i would try, for example, to double it and examine what happens:

sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=131072
An indicator that you have hit into this problem is when the heap dump lists a huge number of open mmap areas (under "Dynamic Libraries" section)

Answer (score 0):

The HotSpot JVM has a feature called CompressedOops wherein it uses 32-bit offsets (compressed oops) on 64-bit platforms in order to have smaller memory footprints and better performance for Java applications. With CompressedOops enabled, 64-bit address values of Java objects are represented as 32-bit offsets using an encoding, and those 64-bit addresses are retrieved back using a corresponding decoding.

The CompressedOops implementation tries to allocate Java heap using different strategies based on the heap size and the platform that an application runs on. If the heap size is less than 4GB, then it tries to allocate it into the lower virtual address space (below 4GB) so that the compressed oops can be used without any encoding or decoding (Unscaled). If that allocation attempt fails or the heap size is greater than 4GB, then it attempts to allocate the Java heap below the 32GB address boundary in order to use the Zero Based compressed oops. If that attempt also fails, then it switches to using regular compressed oops having a Narrow Oop Base. If you are interested in learning more details of the CompressedOops implementation, please refer to CompressedOops.

For CompressedOops enabled JVM (default with 64-bit JVM), the Java heap may get placed in the lower virtual address space leaving very little space for the native heap allocations. This can cause OOM in native memory (even though there is lot of native memory available)

▼ There are 2 possible workaround here

1. Run with -XX:-UseCompressedOops (keeping in mind that you would lose the performance benefit that comes with enabling
   CompressedOops). This will instruct the JVM to run without the CompressedOops feature, and it will not attempt to place the Java
   heap in the first 4GB or 32GB of the address space.
2. Keep CompressedOops enabled, but configure the base of the Java heap using the JVM option -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress=n to
   specify the address where the Java heap should start from.
   If your application is running out of native memory due to a capped/limited native heap, setting this option to a higher address
   would help. If you need the Java heap to be placed beyond 4GB or 32GB then set HeapBaseMinAddress to a value such that
   HeapBaseMinAddress + heap size > 4GB or 32GB. The default value of HeapBaseMinAddress on most platforms is 2GB.

Comment: It looks like the answer consists of copied and pasted content from other pages. This should be marked as a quote then and sources provided as it could be a copyright infringement.